# Android append 2 bitmaps

Tags: android, layout, bitmap

Today I have an issue, i tried to resolve with a inefficient way (popup a dialog with 2 images and create the bitmap) it still explodes anyway... so Im desperate now.

I have seen a lot of masking threads, but not Appending ones.

There is bitmap A and there is bitmap B now, i want to append bitmap A and B to get something like 
consider the gray area, as the bitmap itself.

```
AAAA
AAAA
AAAA
```

+

```
BBBB
BBBB
BBBB
```

=

```
AAAA
AAAA
AAAA
BBBB
BBBB
BBBB
```

As I explained before, I tried with a layout with 2 image views, and this code...

```
public static Bitmap concatenarImagenes(Context oContexto, Bitmap A, Bitmap B)
    {
        if(A==null && B==null) return null;
        if(A==null && B!=null) return B;
        if(A!=null && B==null) return A;

        Dialog oDialogoTicket = new Dialog(oContexto, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
        oDialogoTicket.show();        
        oDialogoTicket.setContentView(R.layout.zutil_concatenate_pictures);

        ((ImageView) oDialogoTicket.findViewById(R.id.img01)).setImageBitmap(A);
        ((ImageView) oDialogoTicket.findViewById(R.id.img02)).setImageBitmap(B);

        ScrollView view = (ScrollView)oDialogoTicket.findViewById(R.id.content);

        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        view.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), 
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight()); 
        view.buildDrawingCache(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache(true));
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); // clear drawing cache
        oDialogoTicket.dismiss();
        return bitmap;
    }
```

I have created pictures with a similar function like this one, but this explodes at this line

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache(true));
```

with this error:

```
07-15 18:08:52.859: E/AndroidRuntime(8102): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1234, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {...VentaSingleActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-15 18:08:52.859: E/AndroidRuntime(8102):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3154)
07-15 18:08:52.859: E/AndroidRuntime(8102):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3197)
07-15 18:08:52.859: E/AndroidRuntime(8102):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-15 18:08:52.859: E/AndroidRuntime(8102):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
07-15 18:08:52.859: E/AndroidRuntime(8102):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-15 18:08:52.859: E/AndroidRuntime(8102):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
07-15 18:08:52.859: E/AndroidRuntime(8102):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4643)
07-15 18:08:52.859: E/AndroidRuntime(8102):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 18:08:52.859: E/AndroidRuntime(8102):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-15 18:08:52.859: E/AndroidRuntime(8102):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
07-15 18:08:52.859: E/AndroidRuntime(8102):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
07-15 18:08:52.859: E/AndroidRuntime(8102):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-15 18:08:52.859: E/AndroidRuntime(8102): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-15 18:08:52.859: E/AndroidRuntime(8102):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:455)
07-15 18:08:52.859: E/AndroidRuntime(8102):     at ...helper.Ticket.concatenarImagenes(Ticket.java:47)
07-15 18:08:52.859: E/AndroidRuntime(8102):     at ...VentaSingleActivity.onActivityResult(VentaSingleActivity.java:114)
07-15 18:08:52.859: E/AndroidRuntime(8102):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4663)
07-15 18:08:52.859: E/AndroidRuntime(8102):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3150)
07-15 18:08:52.859: E/AndroidRuntime(8102):     ... 11 more
```

in the end, what is wrong with my code, and second would be, how would be the correct solution for this problem?

thank you in advance :)

Comment: You got a NullPointerException.  Do you know how to troubleshoot those?

Comment: Yes, is a null pointer exception in 
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache(true)); so the problem is the view? but the view would fail on the previous line view.buildDrawingCache(true); right? so it would fail there... i don't understand what is wrong there...

Comment: I noticed that `who` is null in that `ResultInfo` object cited in the error message.  Could that be the problem?

Comment: hehe but, the error is pointed to this line Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache(true)); so i don't really understand it...

Comment: There's this thing called a Call Stack.  The NullPointerException doesn't have to occur on the method pointed to; it can also occur within any method that the method calls.  In your case, the exception appears to have been thrown in the `deliverResults()` method.

Comment: I know the call stack (that exists, haha) but then how can I know inside Bitmap.java what is throwing null exception? :(

Comment: Try obtaining `view.getDrawingCache(true)` first.  See if that is succeeding.

Comment: it is that. view.getDrawingCache(true) is returning null, but drawing cache is true AND view.isDrawingCacheEnabled() returns true... thanks :) I'm going to try to find out WHY, and or the correct way to put 2 pictures together... :)